# Changing specific column names using pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to change few specific column names of a data frame using dplyr's pipe. Below is one such example -

```
library(dplyr)
head(mtcars)
```

Now let say, I want to change 2nd and 3rd column names to `"a"` and `"b"` respectively. Trivially, I could do it as

```
colnames(mtcars)[2] <- "a"
colnames(mtcars)[3] <- "b"
```

However I want to do it using `pipe` and in a single line to enhance readability.

Any suggestion how should I do it?

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `rename_with`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars <- mtcars %>%
       rename_with(~ c('a', 'b'), 2:3)

names(mtcars)
#[1] "mpg"  "a"    "b"    "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

---

We could use `replace` with `names<-`

```
head(mtcars) %>% 
     `names<-`(replace(names(.), 2:3, c('a', 'b')))
```

-output

```
#                   mpg a   b  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0 6 160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0 6 160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8 4 108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4 6 258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7 8 360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.1 6 225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. However is there any way I can do this using assignment function ` '[<-'() `?

Comment: @BrianSmith Your post says `in a single line to enhance readability.`. I am not sure how that enhances readability

Comment: I am just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: I also noticed that, above approach will work only if all the colnames are unique. For example this code will generate error `%>% rename_with(~ c('a', 'a'), 2:3)`. Is there any way to eliminate this constraint?

Comment: @BrianSmith it generates error because that is not a permitted behavior in data.frame. it is not recommended to even assign dupe names in a data.frame though in matrix it is permitted (but I would avoid doing that)

Comment: I see. But my data set is fetched from some official source and that has multiple columns with same value. I should not change the column names of that original dataset to make them unique. So I need to find a way to change some column-names even if original data has some duplicity.

Comment: @BrianSmith even if you are able to change it to duplicate names, in some subsequent transformation, the `make.unique` will replace it with a unique name

Comment: @BrianSmith I added one option with `names<-`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using `data.table`, then here is another option besides `dplyr`

```
setnames(as.data.table(mtcars), 2:3, c("a", "b"))[]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could simply use `select`:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>%
  select(1, a=2, b=3, everything())
```

Output:

```
> colnames(mtcars)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
> colnames(mtcars1)
 [1] "mpg"  "a"    "b"    "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```